# "no module graphviz error" persist even after installing anaconda and graphviz packages

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, graphviz

I am using this piece of code to display decision tree (from O'Reilly book on ML with python). But got an error message that "no module graphviz".

```
with open("tree.dot") as f:
    dot_graph = f.read()
display(graphviz.Source(dot_graph))
```

After spending some time searching for similar questions on this site, this is the workflow of my attempt to fix the problem:

- installed anaconda3
- installed graphviz

  conda install graphviz
- installed python-graphviz

  conda install python-graphviz
- installed pydot as suggested in one of the existing answers

  conda install pydot

Still no improvement.

I manually added the path to graphviz (I am not sure that /anaconda3//lib/python3.7/site-packages is the right path to graphviz)

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/anaconda3//lib/python3.7/site-packages')
```

which led to a new error:

```
File "/Users/fadoua/ML/ch1.py", line 318, in <module>
    display(graphviz.Source(dot_graph))
NameError: name 'display' is not defined
```

So, I changed the display function call to

```
graphviz.Source(dot_graph).view()
```

I got series of messages, maybe the most frightening is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dot': 'dot'
```

I am using python on Xcode platform. Do you have any idea how to fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Thats the path to graphviz python api, not the actual graphviz runnable. You need to install the graphviz tool manually from your software manager, (not from pip or python).

Comment: I installed graphviz tool as your suggested. I added the path as follows:  sys.path.append('/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz') but error persists: "NameError: name 'display' is not defined".